# BlackBerry Simulator excessive "No debug information found" warnings

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am getting a lot of warnings while running the BlackBerry simulator in debug mode on Eclipse BlackBerry JDE v 7. From the error log:

```
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en' (4e54f479).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en-1' (4e54f479).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en-2' (4e54f479).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en-3' (4e54f479).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en-4' (4e54f479).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__zh_CN' (4e54f511).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__zh_CN-1' (4e54f511).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__zh_CN-2' (4e54f511).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__zh_TW' (4e54f517).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__zh_TW-1' (4e54f517).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__zh_TW-2' (4e54f517).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__ko' (4e54f4c8).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__ko-1' (4e54f4c8).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__ko-2' (4e54f4c8).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en_GB' (4e54f47f).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en_GB-1' (4e54f47f).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__en_GB-2' (4e54f47f).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__pt' (4e54f4e1).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__pt-1' (4e54f4e1).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__pt-2' (4e54f4e1).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__fr' (4e54f491).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__fr-1' (4e54f491).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__fr-2' (4e54f491).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__pt_BR' (4e54f4e6).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__pt_BR-1' (4e54f4e6).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__pt_BR-2' (4e54f4e6).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__es' (4e54f485).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__es-1' (4e54f485).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__es-2' (4e54f485).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__vi' (4e54f50b).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__vi-1' (4e54f50b).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client__vi-2' (4e54f50b).
No debug information found for 'SecurIDLib' (456c5107).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client_resources' (4e54f51f).
No debug information found for 'net_rim_bis_client_res' (4e54f51c).
[195.804] JVM: bklt[1] @195804: JvmBacklightEnableFor 30 ()
[195.804] VM:-DA 0
[195.867] LCD[0] type: 00004009
[195.867] WM Display [0] width: 00000280
[195.867] WM Display [0] height: 000001e0
[195.882] VM:RSRCv=0
[196.0] VM:+GC(f)w=7
[196.0] VM:-GCt=15,b=0,r=0,g=f,w=7
[196.0] VM:+GC(p)w=7
[196.007] 
[196.007] RX=47.9M,RF=51.8M,FF=40.9M,OF=746.9K,OS=216,ON=9,OR=0,FR=0,TR=0,RR=0,IS=0
[196.007] RA=5.5M,RS=216,RN=9
[196.007] TA=0,TS=0,TN=0
[196.007] PA=0,PS=0,PN=0
[196.007] R0=202.1M,1=3.7M,2=8K,3=156.6K,4=386.3K,9=63.7K,10=332,11=280,12=959.7K,13=44,15=387.8K,20=712,21=52[196.007] 4,23=231.8K,24=6K
[196.007] VM:-GCt=1,b=0,r=0,g=p,w=7,u=0,c=0
[196.023] VM:+CR
[196.023] VM:-CR t=0
[196.023] FS:ESHA 4d
```

The normal simulator runs as usual. I also ran `clean.bat` then cleaned my project, restarted the eclipse but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: i am not sure but,my suggestion is reinstall the  software

Comment: Does it block you in any way? Because those are just warnings that for some resources it does not find info for debugging. But do you really suffer from that in any way? I believe everything should still work as expected.

Comment: @Arhimed Unfortunately no. My problem is it closes down the simulator automatically without any warning or further log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry about it. These messages just point that there are no related .debug files found. Some .cod files are present in simulator folder along with .debug files, which contain information for debug. But part of these .cod files come without .debug files and it is normal.

It won't affect on your application neither on its debugging process.

Comment: I do not think, that normally missing .debug files are the cause of the problem. Seems that there's a network port blocked. Simulator uses a network port (I do not recall now its number). And if this port is blocked/used by other process, simulator does not start. Sometimes this may occur when there's another simulator instance running, or previous simulator instance did not exit properly and left some processes which hold the network port.

Comment: Thanks I also thought the same way as you explained here, now it has started to run normally but with the same logs which is not a problem :)